# aws cli --profile expected one parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to use --profile with aws-cli

```
$ aws s3 ls --profile profile360
```

Works good, but:

```
$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name dev_eventsApi_EventsTable --output > c:\temp\hevo.txt --profile profile360
```

results in

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --output: expected one argument
```

I encounter cases where I have problems working with `--profile`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Output redirection such as `> c:\temp\hevo.txt` is a feature of your operating system's shell (e.g. bash in Linux or cmd on Windows). It's nothing to do with the `--output` parameter that the awscli supports. Also note that `--profile profile360` is associated with `aws dynamodb scan` so it needs to appear *before* you redirect the output of the `aws` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the type of output, for example, text or json. Try this.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name dev_eventsApi_EventsTable --output text --profile profile360 > c:\temp\hevo.txt
```

Comment: Beat me to it by mere seconds.